# Is there a rep() function in a package in Julia?

Tags: r, julia

I am looking for a function in Julia that has can take values similar to this R code:

```
rep(1, ncol(X))
```

I know I can use the package DataFrames for the `length` function for the `ncol()` function in R, but I can't find a `rep` function in Julia. 
Thank you!

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but Julia also has `ntuple(f::Callable, n::Integer)` which is the same as `((f(i) for i in 1:n)...,)`. If you pass a function that ignores its input then you can repeat a value `n` times. This is what I was looking for when I ended up at this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The equivalent of `rep` in Julia is `repeat`. As arguments it takes an `AbstractArray` and two keyword arguments `innner` (like `each` in R) and `outer` (like `times` in R). The benefit of `repeat` is that it works consistently with multidimensional arrays (you can have a look at the documentation for details).

For example:

```
julia> repeat([1,2,3], inner=2, outer=3)
18-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 1
 2
 2
 3
 3
 1
 1
 2
 2
 3
 3
 1
 1
 2
 2
 3
 3
```

in Julia gives you the same as:

```
> rep(c(1,2,3), each=2, times=3)
 [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 2 2 3 3
```

in R.

EDIT:
If you want to repeat a scalar use `fill`, e.g.:

```
julia> fill(1, 5)
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 1
 1
 1
 1
```

Comment: But one thing I haven't been able to find in Julia is the equivalent of `rep(1:3, each = 1:3)` giving `1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3`

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński I don't know R, but the initial text in the answer says "innner (like times in R) and outer (like each in R)", but from the code it seems the other way around - `inner` seems the equivalent of `each` and `outer` of `times`. Is that correct? (btw I must say I like the R names better, they seem more descriptive of their role and make it easier to remember what they do.)

Comment: @sundar: you are right - I mixed the names (in the example it was correct). I have fixed this. Thank you.

Comment: @Michael: I would use ` vcat(fill.(1:3, 1:3)...)` but of course it is not a clean solution.

Comment: nice though @BogumiłKamiński

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to use `inverse_rle` from `StatsBase` for `R`'s `rep` using `each`.

```
using StatsBase
inverse_rle(1:3, 1:3)'
#1×6 adjoint(::Vector{Int64}) with eltype Int64:
# 1  2  2  3  3  3
```

---

Benchmark

```
using StatsBase, BenchmarkTools
@btime inverse_rle(1:10, 1:10)
#  68.641 ns (1 allocation: 496 bytes)

@btime vcat(fill.(1:10, 1:10)...)  # @Bogumił Kamiński
#  526.042 ns (12 allocations: 1.62 KiB)
```